# Email-To-Case should not create case and should not send mail to case owner

Tags: case, email2case, case-object

I want to implement the following in Email-To-Case:

Email to case should ONLY be for the following scenario: When case support contacts the customer via email feed and customer responds back then email should be logged in salesforce. Email to case should NOT create new case, in order to avoid spam case creation.

To achieve this I have done the following:

1. I have written a validation rule to stop creating new case from Email-To-Case.

But the issue is that the default case owner is getting email that case couldn't be created. Why is salesforce sending mail to default case owner when the case is not even created ?  How can I stop this behaviour ?

Regards,
Avinash

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't

This email arises whenever E2C fails to create a Case. There are other possible reasons:

- You inadvertently introduced Validation Rules that prevent some (or all E2C) from being created
- The from email address is too large to fit the field size
- Other data validation restrictions violated

The Default Case Owner gets the notification as someone should get notified so corrective action can take place.

In many orgs, the default Case Owner is a service account (i.e. not tied to a specific user) and is used to alert the sysad(s), perhaps through a distro list

If you want to never see these errors, use a filter in the default case owner's email inbox to auto-trash them